# Regex pattern to match substring

Tags: python, regex

Would like to find the following pattern in a string:

`word-word-word++` or `-word-word-word++`

So that it iterates the `-word` or `word-` pattern until the end of the substring.

the string is quite large and contains many words with those^ patterns.
The following has been tried:

```
p = re.compile('(?:\w+\-)*\w+\s+=', re.IGNORECASE)
result = p.match(data)
```

but it returns NONE. Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: Try `p.findall(data)`

Comment: I can't comment, so in putting this in an answer. My favorite thing for stuff like this is to use regexr.com to test some trial data with the regex in question. I always find what I'm missing when I do it that way. Also, as noted, findall grabs all matches. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, try to prepend the pattern with `-?`. Note your question is unclear. Please add sample input and expected output - your current regex does not match your description.

Comment: why do you have `=` at the end?

Comment: you can play with regex in http://pythex.org/

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will only match the first pattern, match() will only find one occurrence, and that only if it is immediately followed by some whitespace and an equals sign.

Also, in your example you implied you wanted three or more words, so here's a version that was changed in the following ways:

1. match both patterns (note the leading `-?`)
2. match only if there are at least three words to the pattern (`{2,}` instead of `+`)
3. match even if there's nothing after the pattern (the `\b` matches a word boundary. It is not really necessary here, since the preceding `\w+` guarantees we are at a word boundary anyway)
4. returns all matches instead of only the first one.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

data=r"foo-bar-baz not-this -this-neither nope double-dash--so-nope -yeah-this-even-at-end-of-string"
p = re.compile(r'-?(?:\w+-){2,}\w+\b', re.IGNORECASE)
print p.findall(data)
# prints ['foo-bar-baz', '-yeah-this-even-at-end-of-string']
```